# i5-4670 in a mITX build

Tags: graphics-card, ssd, cpu, cooling, mini-itx

I'm assembling a rig for multimedia production, running programs like 3Ds max and CSS Suite. Going for the i5-4670, no OC required :)

My build only needs a SSD and a HDD. Will 450W be enough ? Can it handle a low profile GPU of the likes of a GeForce GT610 2GB GDDR3 ?

Comps:

- **CASE:** B-Move Trim MicroATX 450W
- **CPU:** Intel i5-4670
- **MEM:** 8GB 1600 DDR3RAM
- 120GB SSD
- 1TB HDD
- **GPU:** GeForce GT610 2GB GDDR3

Has anyone used that case or can please advise me if it is adequate? My fear is that it won't move heat so good and will probably have to pick a CPU cooler.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it is a hardware shopping question. This is not on-topic for SuperUser. We regularly chat about this kind of thing in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) but you'll need 20 rep (only 14 to go!) to participate

Comment: Also -- to attempt an "informal" throwaway answer to your question -- it should be fine. I don't have any direct experience with this case, but the GT610 is very low power and very low heat emission, and the required TDP is well under 450W for this small build. It seems fine, except that I might even recommend a more powerful GPU (and thus larger case with better thermal profile...) for 3DSMAX and Adobe Creative Suite. You'd be surprised how much GPU power those programs can suck down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power supply that is in that case will provide more than enough power. According to [NVidia's Website](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications), the GT610 only needs a 300W PSU so the 450W should be fine.

Since you are planning on doing a lot of multimedia editing, the computer is going to be generating a lot of heat and the case you have selected is not very good at dissipating heat. It only has one fan on top and just a few vents on the side and back for passive cooling.

If you could fit another fan inside the case to push heat out, then you could use this case but you should think about getting a case with a bit more vents and another fan or two.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I'm really committed to keeping it fairly portable, so the casing size is kind of an issue. Because of this, I'll consider an i5-4570S. Although having a lower speed, I can Turbo Boost it for renders only, keeping the power down and heat controlled at all other times. Do you think this is a good idea ? It's my first multimedia production rig, so pardon me if I ask stupid questions. I'm in need of gauging the possibilities.

Comment: Having the 4570S will cut down on cooling needs as it is designed for saving power. I think what you have now will work with the case. But as @allquixotic said, I would recommend a more powerful GPU because 3DS and Creative Suite love as much GPU power as possible when rending projects

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hardware:

- i5-2500K stock
- ASUS Radeon HD 7870 GHz edition
- 16GB (4x4) of DDR3 1600 RAM (PC3 12800)
- 1x 240GB SSD
- 1x 1TB Caviar Black
- 2x 500GB Caviar Blue
- 1x Corsair TX750 (750 watt PSU)

Loaded up my CPU to 100%
Loaded memory to all 16GB
Loaded GPU with FurMark

P3 Kill-A-Watt reading was about 320 watts at PC plug

---

High-end gaming at 1080p gets to about 220-240

Keep in mind that there is a sweet spot in terms of power efficiency with PSUs so I definitely would need a minimum 500w PSU for my rig.

---

If your case cannot handle the heat then invest in some quiet fans that can create a wind tunnel effect from the front of the PC to the rear